# Can't access header

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have my source C++ code in a folder and a separate header file named "console.h" in another folder which my source code includes. You can see this as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

I keep on getting the error atal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'console.h': No such file or directory. I am pretty sure it is because the header is not in the same location as the source code file (it is in a different folder). Can I use a header in a different folder in my source code? If so, how? I am new to C++ and just started coding in it today. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition as my compiler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify the path in the include statement so that the path is correct relative to the source file:

```
#include "folder\console.h"
```

or add the path to the include directories for the project.

To do this **for all projects** right click the project and go to the "VC++ Directories" property page. There add your folder to the "Include Directories" list.

To do this **for just this project** right click the project and go to the "C/C++ > General" property page and add your folder to the "Additional Include Directories list.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path to `console.h` to tell the compiler how to find it. You can specify either a full path (inadvisable) or as a path ***relative to the location of the current .cpp file***.

For example, if `console.h` was in the parent folder, you would specify:

```
#include "..\console.h"
```

If it was in a separate folder at the same level, say an "includes" folder, you might specify:

```
#include "includes\console.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can run correctly if you header file and .cpp file are in the same directory.
or, you have to use the relative path when you invlude the header file.

for example:

```
#include "../folder/console.h"  //Linux flatform
```

or:

```
#include "..\\folder\\console.h"  //Windows
```

If you're using visual studio, you can add the directory of the folder to the header directory of the project.

Comment: FTR, you can use `#include "../folder/console.h"` in Windows, too, which really helps when you go cross platform ;)